# Razor website on IIS 7

Tags: iis-7, razor, web, webserver

I have developed a website using Razor (Microsoft WebMatrix) and now I want to make it available on an intranet. My server is running Windows Server 2008 Standard. The problem is that when I try to access the website I get the following error: HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden, The web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.

If anyone have seen this error before or knows how to fix it, please tell me. I have found a lot of similar problems on forums but none of the solutions worked for me.

Comment: Did you set the default document in IIS to `Index.cshtml` or whatever you are using?

Comment: It is supposed to be Default.cshtml, so yes I did...

Comment: How about the permissions on the directories - does the user under which IIS is running have read and execute permissions?

Comment: Yes it has read and execute permissions...

Comment: Hrm... that's a bummer.  I thought this might easier than it is ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working, I just had to add the next lines to the web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```